# ProFTPD issue - fail at LIST

Tags: ftp, centos-7, proftpd

i use plesk 17.0.17 #Update 4 and centOS 7.2.1511.

I cannot connect via ftp

the secure log says:

```
proftpd: pam_listfile(proftpd:auth): Couldn't open /etc/ftpusers
proftpd[3623]: 0.0.0.0 (xx.xx.xx) - USER xyz: Login successful.
proftpd: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user xyz by (uid=0)
proftpd: pam_env(proftpd:setcred): Unable to open config file: /etc/security/pam_env.conf: No such file or directory
proftpd: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to connect to system bus: No such file or directory
```

Filezilla says:

```
Status: Resolving address of www.xyz
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xx,xx).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I changed the /etc/pam.d/proftpd like in https://kb.plesk.com/en/125519 without success.

"plesk repair ftp" didn't work. What other things should I be looking for.

- FTP (port 21) worked fine before. The only change that i did was to the sshd and nothing else.
- Users unable to access FTP, keeps failing at "LIST"

Thanks

---

UPDATE 1:
It is very strange but all of a sudden, for no reason, system is working... no idea why. Thanks for you replies!

Comment: Failure to retrieve a directory listing won't be caused by PAM issues.  As @Martin mentioned, it's more likely due to NAT/firewalls.  For ProFTPD, the [NAT howto](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/NAT.html) might be useful for showing what other configuration you may need.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically due to some firewall or NAT on the way between the client and the server blocking the data connection port range.

While usually the culprit is the firewall on the FTP server itself, I'd assume Plesk to take cake of that itself. Anyway, the first test is to try to connect (in the passive mode) from the FTP server itself.

See *my* article about [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand how the passive mode works.